# YouTube API upload "A task was cancelled"

Tags: file-upload, youtube, youtube-data-api

We have been running a service for over a year now that uploads videos to YouTube using the API v3 Upload (using the .NET library Google.Apis.YouTube.v3).

In the last two days we have suddenly started having all uploads fail part way through upload, with the error being returned from YouTube "A task was cancelled".  The videos are partially uploaded on YouTube, they are getting through varied progress (some only a couple of MB, some as much as 17-20MB, though it does appear that the larger progress ones are in the earlier list of failures).

This happened first on Friday night and I was able to push all the failed videos on Saturday morning without incident, but then later on Saturday morning it started again, and since hen all videos on Saturday afternoon and evening failed. We're talking about a total of 25 or so videos, so not hundreds. The videos are all around 40MB in size.

Only 2-3 videos would usually be uploading at once.  While I was successfully pushing them all up on Saturday morning I was actually pushing up about 4-5 at a time.

Can anyone else suggest a possible cause, or any troubleshooting tips? We haven't seen any server connectivity issues otherwise, and the website that runs on this server hasn't had any apparent issues.  I can't see any other error coming back other than this "A task was cancelled" error from YouTube, and up until that error the progress from the uploader is success.

Edit: I've also been able to reproduce this issue running one of our uploads from my dev environment. I've just tried getting a whole new set of API credentials (which are actually for a different YouTube account), refreshed the oAuth token and still having the same issue.

Comment: I'm seeing this with several customers of my application from various countries around the world. I haven't changed any code but I have updated the API in a recent release. I can reproduce the issue on my development machine but I haven't started investigating except to see that it comes from the API in the progress changed event and not my code.

Comment: I think I've identified the issue. Increasing the YouTubeService.HttpClient.Timeout has hopefully fixed it for me. The default was 1 minute 40 seconds. Upping it to 10 minutes seems to be working at the moment. I'll make it user adjustable. The exception returned from the API is a "Task Cancelled Exception", which is the same as if a user cancels the upload for me so I need to work around that somehow.

Comment: You, Sir, are a legend!  I had got to the point where I was just using workarounds to run the uploads each morning (when it works 95% of the time).
So it sounds as if the YouTube servers may be taking longer than usual to respond to uploads, hence the issue arising (and obviously at certain tmies of the day it's more busy then others, hence it usually working in the mornings).
Are you using the .NET library, and if so where are you setting this timeout? Do you mind sharing it (perhaps as an answer, because I'll be wanting to mark this as the answer if it works)?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you find that the timeout change resolved your issue?  If so, do you mind sharing your solution? I've struggled to get it to work, as using the async methods doesn't seem to be persisting the change to the timeout value.

Comment: Can someone share where to change the timeout? i can't find out. @Mick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the timeout before you use the service and, if the user changes it, you need to pause all uploads, null the service and initialise it again.

I'm pretty sure I can confirm setting the YouTubeService.HttpClient.Timeout does solve the question.

Apologies for my delay to respond.

```c#
internal YouTubeService YouTubeService { get; set; }

internal async Task InitialiseYouTubeServiceAsync(int timeoutSeconds)
{

    var scope = new List<string> { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, };
    var clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets()
    {
        ClientId = Constants.ClientId,
        ClientSecret = Constants.ClientSecret
    };

    var fileDataStore = new FileDataStore(Constants.FileDataStore);         

    try
    {

        var credentialTask = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            clientSecrets, scope, Environment.UserName, CancellationToken.None, fileDataStore);

        //This is a hack to allow a progress bar timeout when the user closes the 
        //browser without authorising. It's not associated with the question at hand.
        await Task.WhenAny(credentialTask, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds)));

        if (credentialTask.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation) return;

        var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentialTask.Result,
            ApplicationName = Constants.ApplicationName,                    
        };

        YouTubeService = new YouTubeService(initializer);               

        //This is the answer to the question at hand.
        YouTubeService.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Settings.Default.TimeoutMinutes);              

    }
    catch (AggregateException)
    {
        Exceptions.LogSilent(new Exception(ResourceExceptions.AuthorisationDenied), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

}
```

Comment: Users of my application have confirmed the timeout change shown here has rectified the issue for them.

Comment: Sorry for my delay in returning to this... but I'm happy to report that setting the timeout (which WAS a simple thing in my code, I was just going about it wrong originally) works for me, too, thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for your sample code and your explanation of the "Task Cancelled" issue. I started seeing this occurring this week. After many retries that failed at different places, I decided to search SO and found your solution. I started an upload a few minutes ago and already see response delays of 02:43 and 06:18. The default timeout of 01:40 worked for me for several years but several times in the last few days, I received "Task Cancelled" failures. Setting the timeout to a large value (10 min) seems to have solved the issue. I guess YouTube's upload servers are extremely busy right now.