# "The Task Was Cancelled" HTTP Client default timeout value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, youtube, youtube-api

i want to upload the video by using youtube upload data api but unfortunately when i tried to upload the video it generate the errot that A Task was Cancelled `await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();` 
in my code i already have apply the AsyncTimeout attribute my action is

```
[AsyncTimeout(3600000)]
public async Task <ActionResult> YouTube(int? Id)
{
    // await Run();
    var dbListVideos = db.Videos.Where(v => v.Id == Id).ToList();
    await YouTubeHandler.UploadVideos(dbListVideos);
    return View();
}
```

it invokes the API of YouTube which is

```
 public static async Task UploadVideos(List<MyVideo> videosList)
    {
        foreach (var vid in videosList)
        {
            await Upload(vid);
        }
    }
    public static async Task Upload(MyVideo newVideo)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("G:\\client_secret_783534382593-0cn4gm229raqq97kdu0ghsj9hqfsc5o1.apps.googleusercontent.com.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });



            Video video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = newVideo.Title;
            video.Snippet.Description = newVideo.Description;
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { newVideo.Tags };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = newVideo.Category; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = newVideo.PrivacyStatus; // or "private" or "publi
            var filePath = newVideo.Path; // Replace with path to actual movie file.


        // YouTubeHandler t = new YouTubeHandler();
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest =   youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }
        }


   static void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
    {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                    break;

                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                    break;
            }
        }

      static void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.",       video.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me please as i am new in ASP and Async Task

Comment: have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35008208/1129995  try setting timeout for YouTubeService.HttpClient.Timeout

Comment: i look at this answer but not helping for me !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube API upload "A task was cancelled"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249180/youtube-api-upload-a-task-was-cancelled)

Comment: this is not working in my code

Comment: i already tried it

Answer (score 5):

I had found the solution of this problem You need to set the timeout before you use the service.

```
        YouTubeService youtubeService = new YouTubeService(initializer);
        youtubeService.HttpClient.Timeout= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
```

this will solve the task cancelled problem. Thank you

Comment: Thanks this solved a similar issue I had with the Google Analytics API.